# Asking for a better way for managing a recyclerview with a viewpager inside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have implemented a recyclerview with user posts.
Each post may have a text with the post description and some other icons for other dependencies. 
When the user creates a post, it is possible to add up to 9 pictures, up to 9 videos and some links to youtube videos.

Now, the recyclerview item shows the profile image from the user that has created and some other textviews with some user information. There is also a viewpager inside the item, the viewpager includes the pictures, videos and youtube videos added by the user to the post.

The images inside the viewpager are shown right, the video files are playable, and the youtube videos are also playable.

In fact all that is working fine, now that there are not to many post to show.

My question is what will happen when the number of posts will be huge.

Which is the best way to manage this kind of recyclerview when each item contains a viewpager in it, and each viewpager contains images and videos that are downloaded from a remote server at real time?
Is there some library that does this work?
I guess I will come intro troubles when the number of post will increase.

Would I have a better performance replacing the viewpager with another recyclerview to show the pictures and videos?

Comment: What library you are using for image loading and what about video playing library ?

Comment: for an instance, you can replace `ViewPager` in the item with `ViewPager2` which is built on `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz, I am using Glide for image loading and  for video playing exoplayer

Comment: @DarShan, I don´t understand your proposal, the viewpager is already built in the recyclerview.

Comment: NO, `ViewPager` and `ViewPager2` are both different components. `ViewPager2` is built by extending the existing `RecyclerView`, which gives you the same behaviour as ViewPager but gives robust features of RecyclerView too. try searching for RecyclerView + Pagination examples. :)

Comment: @mvasco For large data, I faced only memory issue only.Since you are using Glide, there is no problem will be in image loading.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz, and there is no way to improve the memory  management?

Comment: @DarShan, thank you, may be this is a good alternative

Comment: Try to load with large dummy data, and monitor the memory in android studio. Still the memory is pretty huge. You may  replace the viewpager with recyclerview for performance imporvement.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz, I guess the first step will be to replace the viewpager with a recyclerview inside the recyclerview and the second step will be to implement pagination like DarShan proposes

Comment: @mvasco Pagination with scroll to load would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`Pagination`** logic. You load and display small chunks of data at a time. Loading partial data on demand reduces usage of network bandwidth and system resources. When next data is loading, it will show a **`ProgressBar`** at the bottom.

[image]